# Class not being read ... Unknown type name

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, class

I'm unsure what is going on or what I changed, but all of a sudden a class I'm trying to reference "that is in the project tree" and in the folder (when I "show in finder") isn't being read at all ... I get multiple errors on the same line of code [see attached].

[image]

Please Help!!!

---

The issue occurs when I try to import HomeViewController.h into my MainContainerViewController

Works:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface MainContainerViewController : UIViewController {

ViewController *parent;

NSString *FACING;
IBOutlet UIView *container;

IBOutlet UIView *topNav;

IBOutlet UIButton *homeBTN;
IBOutlet UIImageView *homeImg;
IBOutlet UILabel *homeLabel;
IBOutlet UIImageView *seperator1;
IBOutlet UIButton *bookmarksBTN;
IBOutlet UIImageView *bookmarksImg;
IBOutlet UILabel *bookmarksLabel;
IBOutlet UIImageView *seperator2;
IBOutlet UIButton *favouritesBTN;
IBOutlet UIImageView *favouritesImg;
IBOutlet UILabel *favouritesLabel;
IBOutlet UIImageView *seperator3;
IBOutlet UIButton *notesBTN;
IBOutlet UIImageView *notesImg;
IBOutlet UILabel *notesLabel;
IBOutlet UIImageView *seperator4;
IBOutlet UIButton *fontBTN;
IBOutlet UIImageView *fontImg;
IBOutlet UILabel *fontLabel;
IBOutlet UIImageView *seperator5;
IBOutlet UIButton *settingsBTN;
IBOutlet UIImageView *settingsImg;
IBOutlet UILabel *settingsLabel;

NSString *drawerIsAnimating;

//SETTINGS (LOCAL)
NSString *fontSize;
```

etc.

Broken:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "HomeViewController.h"

@interface MainContainerViewController : UIViewController {

ViewController *parent;

NSString *FACING;
IBOutlet UIView *container;

IBOutlet UIView *topNav;

IBOutlet UIButton *homeBTN;
IBOutlet UIImageView *homeImg;
IBOutlet UILabel *homeLabel;
IBOutlet UIImageView *seperator1;
IBOutlet UIButton *bookmarksBTN;
IBOutlet UIImageView *bookmarksImg;
IBOutlet UILabel *bookmarksLabel;
IBOutlet UIImageView *seperator2;
IBOutlet UIButton *favouritesBTN;
IBOutlet UIImageView *favouritesImg;
IBOutlet UILabel *favouritesLabel;
IBOutlet UIImageView *seperator3;
IBOutlet UIButton *notesBTN;
IBOutlet UIImageView *notesImg;
IBOutlet UILabel *notesLabel;
IBOutlet UIImageView *seperator4;
IBOutlet UIButton *fontBTN;
IBOutlet UIImageView *fontImg;
IBOutlet UILabel *fontLabel;
IBOutlet UIImageView *seperator5;
IBOutlet UIButton *settingsBTN;
IBOutlet UIImageView *settingsImg;
IBOutlet UILabel *settingsLabel;

NSString *drawerIsAnimating;

//SETTINGS (LOCAL)
NSString *fontSize;
```

etc.

Comment: Please, avoid writing full sentences in caps. It's not only unpleasant to read, like EULA per example, it also means you're shouting at us. You can use styles if you need to hilite some parts of your question.

Comment: Note that there is no error on the import statement, suggesting that the .h file was found OK.  There's something preventing the class from being fully declared -- a misplaced semicolon, missing @end statement, etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may have a header import cycle.

Add

```
@class MainContainerViewController2;
```

just before

```
@interface HomeViewController2
```

It should solve that particular issue.

As a rule of thumb, you shouldn't #import headers in headers if you do not have an absolute need to do so, ie. a superclass header. If you need to use a class, declare it with @class instead of importing the class header. Do that and you should be safe 99% of the time.

Comment: If there's a cycle it's more likely to be in the .h file itself.

Comment: Absolutely. MainContainerViewController2.h most certainly imports HomeViewController2.h, or whatever the files are called.

Comment: Something's fishy in MainContainerViewController2.h then. Could you provide some details?

Comment: Yes, it seems that I was importing MainContainerViewController into HomeViewController, and then was importing HomeViewController into MainContainerViewController ... thanks.

Comment: Cool. Glad I could help. I edited my answer about the use of #import in headers, and @class. This may help for the future. :)

Answer (score 0):

The file may not be included in the target you are building.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check MainContainerViewController2 target.

Click on MainContainerViewController2 .m and .xib and check in the Utilities panel (View > Utilities > Show File Inspector) if the checkbox is ticked into Target Membership section.

Comment: The .h should not have the membership box checked.

Comment: Both the .m and .xib files have that checkbox checked

Comment: Hot Licks correct observation. Chris, try `@class MainContainerViewController2`before `@interface`

Answer (score 0):

First check VERY CAREFULLY your MainContainerViewController2.h file to see if there are any wayward characters anywhere in the file.