# Unknown type name when trying to include a library

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to use [Novocaine](https://github.com/alexbw/novocaine/) in an iPhone application I'm building. I can't figure out how to get around this error I'm getting:

```
Unknown type name 'RingBuffer'
```

Here's my file structure:

[image: File structure]

...with those files under Novocaine being the ones pulled from the Github repo for Novocaine. Here's my header file for DDViewController.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import "UICoordButton.h"
#import "Novocaine.h"
#import "RingBuffer.h"
#import "AudioFileReader.h"
#import "AudioFileWriter.h"

@interface DDViewController : UIViewController
{
    RingBuffer *ringBuffer;
    Novocaine *audioManager;
    AudioFileReader *fileReader;
    AudioFileWriter *fileWriter;
}
- (IBAction)changeColor:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)changeColor2:(id)sender;
@end
```

I've tried a solution that I found on [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11163581/class-not-being-read-unknown-type-name), which suggests that this should work:

```
@class RingBuffer;
@interface DDViewController : UIViewController
{
...
```

But that just gives me `Redefinition of 'RingBuffer' as a different kind of symbol.`

How can I fix this problem and use `RingBuffer`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer (or I guess a combination of answers):

Follow coryalder's advice for setting the compiler default to Objective-C++ as described [here](https://github.com/alexbw/novocaine/issues/17).

Also, change all `.m` files to `.mm` files, and finally add `-fno-objc-arc` compiler flags to all the .mm files -- which is described in detail [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project)

Answer (score 1):

`RingBuffer` is a C++ class. I recommend you change the extension of your Objective-C files from `.m` to `.mm` which will make them Objective-C++

Comment: Just did that as well as adding `-fno-objc-arc` compiler flags to all the `.mm` files, which fixed a bunch of errors... yet my original problem still persists.

Comment: @varatis Please note that you will need to change extension to all `.m` files that #import and indirect #import `DDViewController.h`

Comment: I figured it out by just changing the compiler default to Objective-C++ for the project, but yeah, that would work too probably.