# UIView is unknown when imorting NAMapKit to make custom map app

Tags: objective-c, swift, dictionary, import

When I import the `NAMapKit` library into my Swift project I receive this error:

> Unknown type named 'UIView'

Other libraries work with the same importing steps. Why am I receiving this error?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11163581/class-not-being-read-unknown-type-name...did you see this?

Comment: Thx！I solved that by declaring it with @class.